# Keras Model nested inside of Custom Keras Layer

Tags: keras, nested, layer

I would like to build a Keras model which uses a numerical SPICE-like method for forward propagation. Since SPICE problems are not analytically-solvable, I have built the following class. The class works very well to implement prediction (numerical forward prorogation) and determine gradients (analytically).

Class:

```
# "..." notes places where code is ommited for conciseness

class SPICE_solver():
    def __init__(self, num_inputs, num_outputs, ...):
    ...
        self.net = build_model_SPICE_solver(num_inputs, num_outputs, ...)

    def predict(self, activations, weights, ...):
        '''
        :param activations:         shape: (?, num_inputs)
        :param weights:             shape: (1, num_inputs, num_outputs)
        :return: vout               shape: (?, num_outputs)
        '''
        ...
        out = np.zeros([activations.shape[0], weights.shape[-1]])
        self.net.fit(x=[activations, weights],
                     y=[out],
                     epochs=200,
                     callbacks=[EarlyStoppingByLossVal(monitor='loss', value=self.acc, verbose=0)],
                     verbose=0,
                     steps_per_epoch=64)
        self.vout = self.net.get_weights()
        return self.vout    # weights incidate the output of the 'layer'

    def gradients(self, activations, weights, ...):
        '''
        :param activations:         shape: (?, num_inputs)
        :param weights:             shape: (?, num_inputs, num_outputs)
        :return: gradient:          list of gradients for: activations, weights (w.r.t. vout)
        '''
        ...
        outputTensor = self.net.output
        listOfVariableTensors = self.net.input
        gradients = K.gradients(outputTensor, listOfVariableTensors)
        sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
        sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
        self.grad = sess.run(gradients, feed_dict={self.net.input[0]:activations, self.net.input[1]:weights})
        return self.grad
```

I would like to use this class to accomplish forward-propagation (SPICE_solver.predict) and back-propagation (SPICE_solver.gradients) in a custom higher-level Keras layer.

Custom Keras Layer:

```
class mac_nonLin_SPICE(Layer):

    def __init__(self,
                 output_dim,
                 **kwargs):
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        super(mac_nonLin_SPICE, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        # Create a trainable weight variable for this layer.
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel',
                                      shape=(1, int(input_shape[1]), self.output_dim),
                                      initializer='glorot_uniform',
                                      # constraint='UnitNorm',
                                      trainable=True)
        self.slvr = SPICE_solver(int(input_shape[1]), self.output_dim)
        super(mac_nonLin_SPICE, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this at the end

    def call(self, x):
        return self.slvr.predict(x, self.kernel)

    # def reutrn gradient():????
    # pass

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0], self.output_dim)
```

I am having many issues calling a Keras models in a nested-fashion. Is there a practical way to implement such an object within a custom Keras layer?

**edit**: My intuition tells me that rebuilding the entire design with the low-level TensorFlow APIs is the most practical method, albeit inconvenient. Still searching for an easy Keras work around.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: can you provide more detail on the problems that you are experiencing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, I was unable to accomplish this using Keras. This is the best solution I found:

I recreated the network using Tensorflow low-level API and defined two loss functions:

- Loss1: Mean square of error in the feed-forward path (in other words, if loss1 was high, the SPICE solution was bad)
- Loss2: Mean square error (prediction - training_data)

Then, I set the optimizer to minimize:
Loss = Loss1 + Loss2 * (1 - Gaus(a * Loss1))

Where:

- Gaus() is the Gaussian function, normalized to an amplitude of 1
- "a" is some factor

This way, Loss2 is only minimized when Loss1 is small (when SPICE solution is good).

Hope this helps someone.